# Copy specific Git commits to master branch

Tags: git, merge

I have a **master** and a **development** branch.

I mostly work on the development branch until we can do a sort of release, then merge that branch into master.

Now I added an important commit onto the develop branch, but there's also many other commits there.

Is it possible to "pick" this 1 commit and add it to the master branch, without merging the other commits on my develop branch?

The commit I need is the last commit on the develop branch.

Comment: Suppose that you're in master: `git cherry-pick development` for cherry-picking the last commit in `development`; `git cherry-pick 1234567` for cherry-picking the commit `1234567`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick):

> Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each.

E.g.

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <revision>
```

Answer (score 2):

To "copy" a commit from one branch to another, use the `cherry-pick` command. Make sure you're on on the `master` branch before `cherry-pick`ing.

To checkout the master branch:

```
git checkout master
```

Then `cherry-pick` the commit onto `master`. You'll need to know the commit `<sha>`.

```
git cherry-pick <sha>
```